# I want to display pagination with "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have written pagination code using cdn. So here pagination is working fine in laptop view, Ipad view but coming to mobile responsive pagination is disappearing and when I am removing this "meta viewport" pagination is appearing in mobile responsive So what is the issue here i need help.

```js
<script>
// empty list "rows_p"
let rows = []
// Counting number of "rows" (tr) in under table --> under table body(tbody)
$('#inbox tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
// Then pushing each row into empty list "rows".
    return rows.push(row);
});
// length of list "rows" is less than 31. We are not allowing to show pagination.
if (rows.length < 2){
   $('#pagination-1').hide();
}
// For each 30 lines we are prompting pagination in inbox table.
$('#pagination-1').pagination({
    dataSource: rows,
    pageSize: 1,
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        $('#inbox-1').html(data);
    }
})
</script>
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
#pagination-1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: -117px;
}
#pagination-1 ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.paginationjs-prev {
   border: 1px solid lightgray;
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding: 4px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.paginationjs-next {
   border: 1px solid lightgray;
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding: 4px 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<table id="inbox">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="inbox-1">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste2</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma2</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading2</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars2</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti2</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste3</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma3</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel3</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading3</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars3</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti3</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pagination-1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**pagination CDN**

```
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.1.4/pagination.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagination-1"></div>
<script>
let rows = []
$('#inbox tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
    return rows.push(row);
});
console.log(rows.length);
if (rows.length < 1){
    $('#pagination-1').show();

}
$('#pagination-1').pagination({
    dataSource: rows,
    pageSize: 5,
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        $('#inbox-1').html(data);
    }
})
</script>
```

**css**

```
#pagination-1 {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
          left: -117px;
        }

        #pagination-1 ul li {
          display: inline;
          margin-left: 10px;
        }
        #pagination-2 {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }

        #pagination-2 ul li {
          display: inline;
          margin-left: 10px;
        }

        #pagination-3 {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }

        #pagination-3 ul li {
          display: inline;
          margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .paginationjs-prev {
                border: 1px solid lightgray;
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: 4px 8px 8px 8px;
        }
        .paginationjs-next {
                border: 1px solid lightgray;
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: 4px 8px 8px 8px;
         }
```

**css for mobile responsive**

```
#pagination-1 {
    left: 34%;
    width: 172px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:block
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected HTML on mobile view? Turn on Mobile Preview from devtools. Your code has nothing to do with displaying on different devices, so it must be CSS that hides/shows elements -> we need that information

Comment: I have updated my code with css. please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: Put your code to SO Snippet to inspect

Comment: I have made the snippet and also updated the code